Finding actual classnames from react-atomic-design
I have a project that is using react-atomic-design. It is fairly difficult to find in the code the actual classed components are, because the the classes look like this in the rendered html:
H_1BJQuo p_a T_73HH Z_N W_6D6F e_2qqSFb cZW7ROP_n it_68F4

Which doesn't really help you when you want to trace back to things.
Is there any way to get the original class names from that class?
